# Can not run Javascript from static method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, webmethod

I am trying to run a simple alert script from static method(with intend of running functions in future), but it does not show me the alert(if I do it in page load event it works fine):

```
 Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

  if (page != null)
  {
       string myScript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"Javascript\">";
       myScript += "alert('hi');";
       myScript += "</script>";
       page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.GetType(), "alert", myScript);
   }
```

If I debug the `ClientScript` does run, Can someone help please?

**EDIT**

This is an example script I want to run after the `success event of ajax webmethod`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var OrderReference = '<%= Id %>';
    var EID = <%= EId %>;
    var Comment = '';
    var SubDomain = 'track';

    if (location.protocol.toLowerCase() == 'https:') 
        wgProtocol = 'https';
    else
        wgProtocol = 'http';

    Uri = wgProtocol + '://' + SubDomain + '.test.com/tr.html' + '?&eid=' + EID 
        + '&orderreference=' + OrderReference ;

    document.write('<sc' + 'ript language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript" src="' + Uri + '"></sc' + 'ript>');
</script>

<noscript>
    <img src='http://test.com/transaction.html?ver=1&eventid=<%= EId %>&wgorderreference=<%= Id %>&' alt='' />
</noscript>
```

have already tried to return the above script as string and in ajax method tried following but get `400 bad request` in Firebug:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = result;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

**EDIT 2:**

I created this class :

```
[Serializable]
    public class PixelGenericResults
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Script { get; set; }
    }
```

In my static method I do:

```
 var g = new GenericResults();
 g.Id = 2;
 g.Script = AffiliateTracking.getScript(g.Id); //This gets me the above script

 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
 strReturn = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(g);
```

and in aspx page on success I did :

```
 success: function (result) {
                        if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) { result = result.d; }
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = result.Script;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

but when running it I get this error in firebug `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:5822/undefined"`

Comment: How is the method invoked?  What calls it?

Comment: I am using ajax to call a static [WebMethod] and that is calling the above method..

Comment: @Zaki that's the point: using AJAX you can't interact with the client page directly on server-side, you have to return some values to the AJAX call and then act client-side by JS to create the alert

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas I can create the simple alert as you described..but imagine if I have a big script, that does document.write and on success of ajax webmethod want to register it...

Comment: Well, you have no other way: if you feel it's too cumbersome to do, use a standard post-back of the page instead of AJAX

Comment: Anyway, I would return a JSON object on the client-side and then using it in JS to update the page

Comment: A [WebMethod] doesn't have any effect on the page that's already been rendered.  Nor does it result in a new page being rendered.  All it can do is pass information back to the client, which can update the page.

Comment: @LittleSweetSeas can you show a sample of what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, you can't directly interact with a page already rendered using an AJAX call, so you have to do some work on client side.

Here an example, based on the code you showed us:

c#:

```
//import this namespace:
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

// declare a class to contain all the info you will need client-side
[Serializable]
public class GenericResult
{
    public int OrderReference  { get; set; }
    public string URL {get; set;}
    public string EID  { get; set; }
    public string Comment  { get; set; }
    // etc. etc.
}

//In your static method, instance and populate such class:
var r = new GenericResult();
r.OrderReference = 34;
r.URL = "http://www.google.com";
r.EID = "someString";
r.Comment = "this will work like a charm";
this.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
this.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(r));
```

JS:

```
//In your AJAX 'onsuccess' callback, you can use the object very easily, eg:
function callback(r){
    var script = document.createElement('script');  
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = r.URL;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

I have not tested this, so it may contains any typos, but that should be enough to let you to adapt your code.

EDIT:

```
 success: function (result) {
    //what is the next line for?!?!?!
    //if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) { result = result.d; } 

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = result.Script;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Please help me to help you. Do a bit of debugging and check where is the issue now, by what i can see i can tell you that your code shouldn't even compile, as *g.RequestId* is not declared in PixelGenericResults class.

Comment: Try also "alert(result);alert(result.Id);" in your JS callback as first statement, to check if the JSON object has correctly arrived there.

Comment: yea my bad had to simplify the class :)..it is fixed. it does compile and can see my script in script property. I did put an alert on script.src and got http://localhost:5822/undefined..sorry am new to this

Comment: Please post your ajax call, as the problem lies there ;)

Comment: have edited it above..edit2...also for alert(result); I can see my properties e.g. id, script etc. but for alert(result.Id); I get undefined..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42883/discussion-between-littlesweetseas-and-zaki)